# Date to day conversion in php

Tags: php

in my webpage i need to calculate the day[ie. SUN,MON,TUE...] from the date .. The date is in ['06/22/2009'] this format ? How can i calculate it in to day[That is it will show me MON] in php . Please help me to find out . Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 25):

First, you need to parse the string '06/22/2009' into a timestamp, possibly using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$dt = strtotime('06/22/2009');
```

Then, you can format the timestamp using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$day = date("D", $dt);
```

If you especially want it in uppercase, use [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php):

```
print strtoupper($day);
```

Answer (score 4):

For future viewers, I think this will be more helpful.

```
echo date('l', strtotime('11/20/2017'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the date 
http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
and strtotime http://au.php.net/strtotime
functions

Answer (score -1):

pls check the funcion. the out put is showing the current day.pls tell me the given date dau in the `date("D",$dat)`

Comment: The post is very low quality. Some improvements are required to make it legible if the answer is correct.