# How can I get the day of a specific date with PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to get the day (Sunday, Monday,...) of October 22. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062196/date-to-day-conversion-in-php

Answer (score 139):

You can use the [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. I'm using `strtotime` to get the timestamp to that day ; there are other solutions, like `mktime`, for instance.

For instance, with the 'D' modifier, for the textual representation in three letters :

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2009-10-22');

$day = date('D', $timestamp);
var_dump($day);
```

You will get :

```
string 'Thu' (length=3)
```

And with the 'l' modifier, for the full textual representation :

```
$day = date('l', $timestamp);
var_dump($day);
```

You get :

```
string 'Thursday' (length=8)
```

Or the 'w' modifier, to get to number of the day *(0 to 6, 0 being sunday, and 6 being saturday)* :

```
$day = date('w', $timestamp);
var_dump($day);
```

You'll obtain :

```
string '4' (length=1)
```

Comment: Hey Pascal, thank you for posting this 6 years ago. It still helped me out, as I am new to PHP. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 27):

```
$date = '2014-02-25';
date('D', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: why not date('I', strtotime($date)); since OP asking for *Sunday, Monday ...* in full text

Answer (score 9):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20151102');

echo $datetime->format('D');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

```
$date = strtotime('2016-2-3');
$date = date('l', $date);
var_dump($date)
```

(i added format 'l' so it will return full name of day)

Comment: This won't help when the date format is different forex. d/m/Y => 10/05/2021. If we use date like this then it will give you the wrong output.

Answer (score 4):

```
$date = '2009-10-22';
$sepparator = '-';
$parts = explode($sepparator, $date);
$dayForDate = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $parts[1], $parts[2], $parts[0]));
```