# How to find Day from date string in PHP?

Tags: php, date

i have string like below `"June 1, 2012"`. i need to find day for the above string.

this value return from wordpress postdate() function.

how can i do this in php?

Comment: A simple search on SO should have answered this for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385801/how-can-i-get-the-day-of-a-specific-date-in-php

Comment: @Aaron W. but i need to get day form above format only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't you parse the date with `strtotime`?
If so, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
date('l', strtotime('June 1, 2012'));
?>
```

Comment: 'l' (lower case L) for full day and 'D' for 3 letter day

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo date('d',strtotime('June 1, 2012')); ?>
```

You can use a variable instead of the static date string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$unix_timestamp = strtotime($date);
echo date('l', $unix_timestamp); // displays Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "June 1, 2012";
echo date('l', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp= strtotime("June 1, 2012");
$day = date('l', $timestamp);

echo $day;
```

For more details, read [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "June 1, 2012"
$day = date('j', strtotime($date))
```

You can do different options in the date function to display the day (or other date parts as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is easily found, you would be best to research first:

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php